# Mapping complex object to dictionary using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

Consider the following object:

```
Controller controller = new Controller()
{
    Name = "Test",
    Actions = new Action[]
    {
        new Action() { Name = "Action1", HttpCache = 300 },
        new Action() { Name = "Action2", HttpCache = 200 },
        new Action() { Name = "Action3", HttpCache = 400 }
    }
};
```

How can I map this object to a dictionary of the following form?

```
#key# -> #value#
"Test.Action1" -> 300
"Test.Action2" -> 200
"Test.Action3" -> 400
```

That is, a `Dictionary<string, int>`.

I am interested in a LINQ solution but I can't manage to work around it.

I am trying to map each action to a KeyValuePair, but I don't know how to get each action's parent controller's Name property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main thing is the controller is still in scope in the lambda:

```
var result = controller.Actions.ToDictionary(
  a => string.Format("{0}.{1}", controller.Name, a.Name),
  a => a.HttpCache);
```

Comment: nice solution but first check if all Name's of Action are unique in list :)

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ approach is to project the Actions list, using the `Select` method, into a dictionary. Since you're calling it on a `Controller` instance, you have access to the Controller's `Name` as well:

```
myController.Actions.ToDictionary(
    /* Key selector - use the controller instance + action */
    action => myController.Name + "." + action.Name, 
    /* Value selector - just the action */
    action => action.HttpCache);
```

If you want to make one large dictionary from *several* controllers, you can use `SelectMany` to project each Controller's items into a list of Controller+Action, then convert that list into a dictionary:

```
var namesAndValues = 
    controllers.SelectMany(controller =>
        controller.Actions.Select(action =>
            { 
              Name = controller.Name + "." + action.Name,
              HttpCache = action.HttpCache
            }));
var dict = namesAndValues.ToDictionary(nav => nav.Name, nav => nav.HttpCache);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
var dico = controller.Actions
                     .ToDictionary(a => $"{controller.Name}.{a.Name}", 
                                   a => a.HttpCache);
```

The first lambda expression target the key whereas the second target the value of the dictionary entry.

Comment: Missing the dot between the two names here: `.ToDictionary(a => $"{controller.Name}.{a.Name}",`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have multiple controllers in a collection, not just the one `controller` variable in your example code, and want to put all of their actions into a single dictionary, then you could do something like this:

```
var httpCaches = controllers.SelectMany(controller =>
    controller.Actions.Select(action =>
        new
        {
            Controller = controller,
            Action = action
        })
    )
    .ToDictionary(
        item => item.Controller.Name + "." + item.Action.Name,
        item => item.Action.HttpCache);
```

This would be for the case where you have your data set up like this:

```
var controllers = new[] {
    new Controller()
    {
        Name = "Test1",
        Actions = new Action[] {
            new Action { Name = "Action1", HttpCache = 300 },
            new Action { Name = "Action2", HttpCache = 200 },
            new Action { Name = "Action3", HttpCache = 400 },
        }
    },
    new Controller()
    {
        Name = "Test2",
        Actions = new Action[] {
            new Action { Name = "Action1", HttpCache = 300 },
            new Action { Name = "Action2", HttpCache = 200 },
            new Action { Name = "Action3", HttpCache = 400 },
        }
    },
};
```